# How to use redis pipiline(StackExchange.Redis) in c#?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have currently tested redis-benchmark on my linux system and was impressed by the results. But while benchmarking, I used pipelining of 16 commands. Now I am trying to execute it on c#. 
My main problem is I want to log some thousands of random data into redis and I can't figure how to used pipelining with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as a side note: the raw performance of SE.Redis isn't quite at the same level as `redis-benchmark`; I have some ongoing work with a v3 of the network layer that is looking very promising, but that's a little way off yet, but: it increases throughput by a good multiple

Answer (score 2):

The most explicit way to use pipelining in StackExchange.Redis is to use the `CreateBatch` API:

```cs
var db = conn.GetDatabase();
var batch = db.CreateBatch();
// not shown: queue some async operations **without** awaiting them (yet)
batch.Execute(); // this sends the queued commands
// now await the things you queued
```

however, note that you can achieve a lot *without* that, since:

- concurrent load from different threads (whether sync or async) [is multiplexed](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/PipelinesMultiplexers.html), allowing effective sharing of a single connection
- the same trick of "issue multiple async operations but don't await them just yet" *still works fine* even without the batch API (using the batch API ensures that the batch is sent as a contiguous block without work from concurrent threads getting interleaved within the batch; this is similar to, but less strict than, the `CreateTransaction()` API)

Note also that in some bulk scenarios you might also want to consider Lua (`ScriptEvaluate()`); this API is varadic, so can adapt to arbitrary argument lengths - your Lua simply needs to inspect the sizes of `KEYS` and `ARGV` ([discussed in the `EVAL` documentation](https://redis.io/commands/eval)).

Comment: Hello thank your for your quick response and thanks for amazing redis client. I have a naive doubt that aren't batching and pipeline are different? ([link](http://taswar.zeytinsoft.com/redis-pipeline-batching/))

Comment: @anandkumarPanigrahi they're not 100% the same, but there are huge overlaps; the `CreateBatch()` API does *both* of them; when you call `Execute`, it doesn't wait for the things to complete and get responses - it just starts sending them in bulk; how you await them (sequentially? individually? all?) is up to you; the advantage of `Execute` here is that it can help reduce packet fragmentation at the same time; otherwise, as I said: you can just issue async operations sequentially

Comment: I tried to implement batching, but at the end i am missing keys. Can you please help @marc (https://pastebin.com/6dvqTMkX)

Comment: @anandkumar what exactly are you trying to do? When we're talking about simply setting keys, there is a varadic StringSet that is probably more appropriate. That code looks to be spending 200ms to build an *epic sized* unsent batch (nothing is sent until Execute, and you can do as lot of buffering in 200ms), all with fire-and-forget. Since they're fire-and-forget, there's really no purpose in waiting on them afterwards: that wait doesn't mean anything *because they are fire and forget*. I'll try and put something together when I'm at a keyboard, but yes: I'd expect that to not work well

Comment: What I am trying to do is to see how much data I can log in every 200ms. I just want best figures. But you have another point of view on my code, so can you please help. It would really helpful.

Comment: @anand try calling Execute every few hundred operations

Comment: I cant understand how can I execute few hundred operations inside my while loop or do you mean something else?

Comment: @anand if the problem is that you're not sure how to carve the sequence into batches, you can grab `Batchify` [from here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1145#issuecomment-492592923). What you do with each batch depends on the operation you are performing. if it is things like `StringSet`: IIRC there is a version off that which takes multiple inputs. But otherwise: `CreateBatch`, do the thing, and `await Task.WhenAll` the results. For a more complete answer, I really need a more complete scenario (i.e. code that shows *what you are trying to do*)

Comment: thanks for input. 
I am trying to find if I can log 65000 or more key-value pairs in 200ms inside Redis. Here is a complete code(https://pastebin.com/dqErEQQ3).

Comment: That's a rate of 325kops/s. It is achievable, but that is at the high end. In some new experimental code I'm working on for SE-Redis with a pool, I'm getting around 400kops/s, but: my measurements are on just an `incr` - I'm not accounting for the bandwidth of the actual thing you're trying to send, and I'm talking to a server on the same machine so negligible latency/network overhead. If you're talking to a more distant server, and your log data is anything more than trivially small, I doubt you'd get 325kops/s from *any* library setup.

Comment: thanks @marc for response.I will be trying other NoSql databases to acheive same feat.

Comment: @anand most of the things I mention: are inherent simply in the data volume and frequency. It isn't about server performance - you're simply saturating the pipe.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand.